# How can I get result of specified table according to user role in collection using Identity 2.0 .NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, collections, asp.net-identity-2

I have one table that represents for example Fruit which has a collection of ApplicationUser. Then in ApplicationUser I add Fruit and FruitId. 
So what I need is the result of Fruit which is according to user role of ONE of ApplicationUser in Fruit.

Here is the model.

```
public class Fruit
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<ApplicationUser> User { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
   // some code 
    public int FruitId { get; set; }
    public virtual Fruit Fruit { get; set; }

}
```

And what I tried is here, but with no success.

```
var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>
        (new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
        var role = roleManager.FindByName("Simple");

var SimpleFruits = db.Fruits.Where(f => f.User.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Roles.Select(y => y.RoleId)).Contains(role.Id));
```